# Connect to Java server socket from google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, sockets

My requirement is this:

Client sends a request to app engine server with some parameter.

The app engine server has to connect to some program running on a windows machine to calculate the response.(I am implementing this program using Java server socket,is that the right thing to do?)

App engine server passes this response to client.

How do I connect to the java server socket from my web application running on google app engine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine does support **outbound** sockets but currently it is available on an experimental basis and only for paid applications.

Please refer to : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/

The above documentation does mention that you cannot create listen sockets but only outbound sockets. Do look at the different conditions under which connection is allowed and see if it meets your needs.

If the current Experimental Status of the API + the fact that it has to be for paid applications does not meet your requirements, then URL fetch might be the way out for you.

In terms of your requirements, do you need that the client be kept waiting to determine the time it takes from your App Engine application to another server? If not, I suggest to accept the request and perform the operation in a separate task. Once the task is complete, it could notify the client back via the Channel API.

Comment: client actually will be an android app.I have used Channel api for talking to client browser,does it work for android too ?

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine provides only the [URL Fetch Java API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/) to make outgoing connections so your external server (on the Windows machine) must run some kind of HTTP or HTTPS server.  AppEngine does not support outgoing connections to arbitrary sockets.